# Node.js Mongoose how to save new document and add new value to array field

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have a `User` model and each `user` document has `name` field which is `String` and `friends` field which is an `array` of integers which holds `id's` of other users who this user is friends with.

Whenever I want to create a new user document with one id already in friends array, I have to three steps: 1. create new user with specific name; 2. save this user; 3. update this user's friends field by adding new friend id to the array.

I was wondering if there is another, more efficient way of achieving the same result. Here is my code so far:

```
var User = mongoose.model('User',{
    friends:  {
        type: [Number],
        required: false      
    },
    name: String
});

            //cretae new user document
            var user = new User ({
                name: name
            });

            user.save(function(err){
                if(err){
                    console.log("something went wrog, read below");
                    console.log(err);
                }else{
                    User.update({'name': name}, {
                        $addToSet: { 'friends': newFriendId}
                    },function(err, count) {
                        if(err){
                            console.log(err);
                        }else{
                            console.log(count);
                        } 
                    }); 
                }
            });
```

Comment: Why are you using Update just after user save ?

Answer (score 1):

```
var User = mongoose.model('User',{
    friends:  {
        type: [Number],
        required: false      
    },
    name: String
});

            //cretae new user document
            var user = new User ({
                name: name,
                friends : [newFriendId] 
            });

            user.save(function(err){
                if(err){
                    console.log("something went wrog, read below");
                    console.log(err);
                }else{


                }
            });
```